# IE 11 issue with Flex

Tags: css, internet-explorer, flexbox, zurb-foundation

I've been looking through here and other forums, trying to fix this IE bug with no luck. Basically, the gray buttons below "FIND THE RIGHT TOOL" (using "cards" in Zurb Foundation, with the Flex grid) are displaying oddly in IE11--as if they have no width set:

http://www.mindtools.io

Here's how it's rendering in IE11: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBl8X.jpg

Any help would be greatly appreciated--thank you!

Comment: Instead of providing external links, add the block of problematic code in a snippet that can reproduce the problem.

Comment: `#find-a-prog, #disorders { width: 100% }`

Comment: Thank you--I tried to isolate the problematic code in CodePen, and wasn't able to. Apologies for the improper question format. Michael, that worked great, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can get the "cards" to be the right width by setting #find-a-prog to width 100% and .disorder to width: 100%. But there are other issues in my view of IE too, like the button bumping up into the cards and the #find-a-prog aligning to the right of the startchange div.

EDIT: corrected a mistake. Also I would suggest making the hero container display block and centering the items in it a different way, maybe with margin: 0 auto;

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you!